# Login as portal user when using custom domain

Tags: customer-portal

Is it possible to use the "login as" feature for our customer portal users if the customer portal is build as a force.com site with a custom web address (www.mysite.com)?

Comment: I asked a [similar question here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/how-do-i-login-as-a-contacts-portal-user-to-force-com-site-that-uses-customer-p), but I ran out of time and didn't get to test any of the answers out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not supported.